# DataGrid, how to add a row of combo boxes?

Tags: wpf

I would like to programatically add a row of combo boxes to a DataGrid control. Ideally this would come in just after the header. So technically the first item row.

Example:

```
Header: ID|Name|Email
ComboRow : [ComboBox]|]ComboBox]|]ComboBox]
ItemsRow : 1|John Doe|john@doe.com
```

Each of the combo boxes will contain the exact same options, and can be statically set, no need to databind.

I got stuck trying to code this when I came across: **DataGridComboBoxColumn** because it seems the whole DataGrid will only follow 1 template. Since the rest of the cells in future rows will contain text, not a great idea.

So I've looked at:

```
DataGridTextColumn  col = new DataGridTextColumn() ;
dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
```

and

```
DataGridComboBoxColumn  col = new DataGridComboBoxColumn() ;
dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
```

but clearly 1 is designed to hold text and another a combobox and these are applied at the DataGrid level, not the row level.

I guess what I am looking for is a column type that could hold any control? If not, a workaround...

EDIT an example:

[image]

Comment: That's the DevExpress `GridControl`. They have invested thousands of man hours to develop that. Anyways I think that picture shows the grid with no column headers and the `AutoFilterRow`. You `could` achieve something like this with the standard WPF `DataGrid` by using custom `Header` Templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, thank you HighCore for the hint in the right direction!:

```
myDataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn {Header = new ComboBox(), Binding = myBinding});
```